# Convert userInfo [AnyHashable: Any] to [String: Any]

Tags: swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I got notification in `didreceiveRemoteNotification` but I can not cast userInfo to dictionary of type [String: Any]

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    let dict = userInfo as! [String: Any]
    if let response = dict["message"] as? [String: Any], let baseResponse = Mapper<NotificationModel>().map(JSON: response) {
      //do some stuff
    }
}
```

when I try to cast dict["message"] as! [String: Any] error happens and it says:

**Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1cfa84f90) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1cfa85bc0).**

Here is dict["message"] when I print it in console:

```
▿ Optional<Any>
  - some : {"sender":

{"avatar_url":"http:\/\/api.moneyar.com\/APIs\/images\/15783070400.jpg","user_id":"15783","name":"mahdi moqadasi"}

,"conversation_id":"15783"

,"message_id":103597,

"time":1546778745,

"type":1,"message":"foo"

}
```

Comment: It seems according to the error that `dict["message"]` is a String, a JSON Stringified. So it's `if let jsonStringified = dict["message"] as? String` that should work. I don't use `Mapper`, but with standards tools: `let jsonData = jsonStringified.data(encoding: .utf8); let jsonDict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(data: jsonData)` in pseudo code.

Comment: @Larme I', going to try your code

Comment: @Larme Please post your comment as an answer. that's correct one. thanks for correcting me

Comment: `Mapper<NotificationModel>().map(JSON: response)`: Does `Mapper` have a way to treat `(NS)Data` or `(NS)String` JSON? Because that should avoid the transformation. I hope that for a higher level third lib it does. Is that the case? Like `Mapper<NotificationModel>().map(JSONString: jsonStringified)` or `Mapper<NotificationModel>().map(JSONData: jsonData)` And are you using this one: https://github.com/lyft/mapper/blob/master/Sources/Mapper.swift ?

Comment: @Larme yes. I just cast jsonDict to [String: Any] and give it to Mapper and it successfully give me a model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the following answer, the code is not tested against a compiler, there might be some typo issue that could be easily fixed, some of them are intentionally done to exergue the logic behind it, and not add with `if let`/`guard let`, `as?`, etc. that are needed but add noise in the explanation.

I won't repeat [@vadian answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54061681/1801544), which is correct an explain why it fails.

So we are clear that `dict["message"]` is a `String`.

A piece of information that you seem to be missing in the JSON acronym is for what stands the "N": Notation.

When you printed `dict["message"]`, you didn't have really a key/value object, you have a String representing a key-value object, but not in a Swift representation. You printed JSON Stringified (because it's clearly more readable that hex data JSON). If after the answer you print `jsonDict`, you'll see that the output structure might be different.

So, as always, your basic tools are:

```
Data <== data(encoding:)/init(data:encoding:) ==> String
Data <== jsonObject(with:options:)/data(withJSONObject:options:) ==> Array or Dictionary //I bypass voluntarily the specific case of String at top level
```

Let's do it then!

```
let jsonStringifiedString = dict["message"] as String
let jsonStringifiedData = jsonStringifiedString.data(using: .utf8) as Data
let jsonDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonStringifiedData, options: []) as [String: Any]
let baseResponse = Mapper<NotificationModel>().map(JSON: jsonDict)
```

If I were you, I'd look into `Mapper` if there is no way to do something like:

```
let baseResponse = Mapper<NotificationModel>().map(JSONData: jsonStringifiedData)
```

or

```
let baseResponse = Mapper<NotificationModel>().map(JSONString: jsonStringifiedString)
```

Because there are sometimes JSONStringified embedded in JSON, where you might need to call it on a `String` or on a `Data` directly. 
Or just because the basic `URLSession` request returns a `Data` object in its closure, and you want to use it directly.

Answer (score 1):

The error

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1cfa84f90) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1cfa85bc0).

is clear. The value of key `message` is a string

- **of type** is the *real* type
- **to** is the expected *wrong* type

---

```
if let response = dict["message"] as? String, ...
```

Comment: That's not an answer.I print dict["message"] and everything is key-value

Comment: @andesta.erfan You are seeing JSON, and that's not how is printed a Swift Dictionary, so not it's not "key value", for now, it's just a JSON String.

Comment: The value is definitely a string. It seems that the string is JSON, you have to deserialize it separately (what you actually do with the `Mapper` object)

Comment: ok.but what do you mean by "it's just a JSON String" ? and how can I cast it to [String: Any]

Comment: Read my comment on your question. JSON is just a representation. The "N" in JSON stands for "Notation". That's always a step that new developers are missing. The Data representation, the String representation, and finally the Dictionary/Array in your own language representation after the serialization. So when there is embeeded JSON Stringified in some JSON, as it's in your case, that's always the same way of resolving it.